# Select first_name where last_name has as second letter 'o'?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle, this information comes from the    "HR.EMPLOYEES" table, but I don't know how to structure that query.

Comment: Ideally, you MUST first search and try yourself for such trivial requirements. The amount of effort you have spent to ask the question, could have been used to look into Oracle **documentation** or millions of examples on the web. I am just giving you a **benefit of doubt** that you are completely new to Oracle database and RDBMS. However, this seems to be a homework assignment. Please see my answer.

Comment: In fact, it's a homework assignment, we're viewing DML, but such queries are new from me. I'm still trying to do what you recommended me, but I just get `no rows selected`, but there are at least eight names with 'o' as second letter.

Comment: Can you show what you tried. I made an effort to explain a lot, I expect a test case from you. I was hoping you wouldlike my answer as a strating point at least. I tried my best to help, against the rules. This topic would be eventually marked as duplicate. I don't want any downvote unnecessarily. Would you, please, make some effort too?

Comment: Please see my edit, there was a silly typo in the `substr` expression.

Comment: This is what I tryied:
`SELECT LAST_NAME
   FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME, 2, 3) = 'o'; `

I didn't know about the `SUBSTR` function, so I researched a little about it, [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) it says here that "length" is optional, and even without it, the result is the same `no rows selected`. These are the following names that are in the `EMPLOYEES` table by default (that have to appear with my condition):
Donald, Douglas, John (x3), Jonathon, Jose Manuel, Joshua, Louise, Mozhe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve your goal. In no particular order:

### Using `SUBSTR`

Just use [`SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm). This function allow you to extract a part from a string:

```
SELECT first_name FROM table WHERE SUBSTR(last_name, 2, 1) = 'o'
```

Remember, you are only filtering the rows based on lower case as 'o' which is not same as upper case 'O'. And, you need to create a `function-based index` on the column too, to avoid any `performance issues` due to `FTS`.

If you have only one column for the name, then use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` in the `SELECT` to get the `first_name`. I would like to leave this up to you. Let me know if you really struggle with `INSTR`. A hint for you to try and learn yourself, `INSTR( string, substring [, start_position [,  nth_appearance ] ] )`

### Using *regular expression*

The same could be achieved using [`REGEXP_LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm), however, it would be much resource consuming:

```
SELECT first_name FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(last_name, '^.o')
```

Here, I am looking for a string such as:

- `^` after the start of the string
- `.` I have *any* character
- `o` then an *o*

### Using `LIKE` pattern matching

This solution is rather database-vendor agnostic: it will work with (almost?) any RDBMS:

```
SELECT first_name FROM table WHERE last_name LIKE '_o%'
```

Pattern matching is more or less like the *wildcard* you might use in your shell. Except than is SQL `_` is used for *any character* and `%` is used for *any string* (incl. empty string).

### Other

By searching through the web and in various Oracle's documentation you might probably be able to find several other -- more or less exotic -- options.

For example, one might think of using a *virtual column* on the second letter of `last_name`.

Or, ***if and only if***, you need case insensitive approach, you can have a look at this demo http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/. Please make sure you have utmost understanding about the trivial aspects as mentioned above, before jumping onto complex things.

Comment: Definitely appreciate your patience and information provided. But sometime, questions would be asked with a fundamental intent of learning something or some assignment etc.. In such case, our efforts will not be valued. Also it might not benefit future users.. As there are so many such questions! Anyway this question would be closed.

Comment: I agree Mahesh. That's why I said, I am just giving OP a benifit of doubt. I don't want to see OP go away thinking nobody helps here in SO, if he understands this time once, he might not repeat it again. I think, we can wait for OP's reply, and then mark the question as **duplicate**, since there must be so many similar questions. At the least, OP would read my comment on the topic,I have told him why the question seems so trivial.

Comment: You will feel the site's philosphy sooner.. Like I learnt.. :) Btw isnt it substr(name,2,1) ?

Comment: Mahesh, thanks for pointing it. Fixed it. My bad, silly one. I had instr in my mind while I was writing about substr. And, I agree, I have already started feeling SO philosophy since I crossed 2000 points. Quite a different feeling from other sites. I can't say `forum` , since I have practically realized that SO is NOT a forum :-)

Comment: A +1 to your helpful comments. Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned regular expression. But why not using simple pattern matching `LIKE '_o%'`. This absolutely not resource intensive and with the added benefice of being rather database vendor agnostic.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about `LIKE`. +1 @sylvain. If properly taken care in SQL, it would be better in terms of performance, and no need of function-based index. Very good point. Since OP's question is not about performance, and that these suggestions are additional information, would you like to edit my answer and add it or yor can add another answer as a continuation. I would leave that to you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Good to see that the SO community collectively helped you. I would wait for sometime for @sylvianleroux to add his suggestion as an additional answer, or I would include it in my answer.

Comment: @Lalit I tried to update your answer. Feel free to revert/edit as appropriate.

Comment: @sylvain, thank a lot. It looks much better now with everything consolidated at one place. My favorite option at last would be a `virtual column`.